# Elasticsearch Query on multiple object fields of an Array of Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a product document that looks like this:

```
{
        "_index": "productss",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2fb60b1880f0251af4340af009",
        "_score": 5.0262785,
        "_source": {
            
            "prepTime": {
                "durationType": "Min",
                "value": 8,
                "imageUrl": ""
            },
            "shopId": "CCXow8ALRDrALRSKFC",
            "productTimings": [
                {
                    "startHour": 8,
                    "endHour": 9,
                    "startMin": 30,
                    "endMin": 45,
                    "dayOfWeek": [
                        "Mon",
                        "Tue",
                        "Wed",
                        "Thu",
                        "Fri"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "startHour": 16,
                    "endHour": 18,
                    "startMin": 30,
                    "endMin": 45,
                    "dayOfWeek": [
                        "Sat",
                        "Sun"
                    ]
                }
            ]
            
        }
    }
```

My model looks like this.

```
const mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const Timing = new Schema({
  startHour: { type: Number, es_indexed: true },
  endHour: { type: Number, es_indexed: true },
  startMin: { type: Number, es_indexed: true },
  endMin: { type: Number, es_indexed: true },
  dayOfWeek: [{ type: String, es_indexed: true }],
});

const productsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
  
  prepTime : {
    durationType : { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    value : { type: Number, es_indexed: true },
    imageUrl : { type: String, es_indexed: true }
},
shopId: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
  
  productTimings: {
    type: [Timing],
    es_indexed: true,
    es_type: 'nested',
    es_include_in_parent: true,
  }
  
});

productsSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema, 'Products');
```

I need to fetch all products whose startHours:Startminute is less than the current time and endHour:endMinute is less than the current time. It should also match the dayOfWeek from current date.

Note that, there could be a morning slot and a evening slot in the productTimings.

I have tried the following and got this far, but cannot proceed further:

````
prodDetails = await client.search({
          index: 'productss',
          body:
          {
            query:
            {
              bool: {
              must: [
                { match: { shopId } },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "productTimings",
                    "query": {
                      "range": {
                        "productTimings.startHour": {
                          "lte": 12,

                        }
                      },
                      "range": {
                        "productTimings.endHour":{
                          "gte": 11,
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }

            },
          },
          from: pageno * size,
          size,
        });```
````

Comment: Hi, I've been using the same package, mongoosastic. The issue I', facing is, when I created a nested index with es_type: 'nested', the mapping generated and updated in elasticsearch is still of general flattened object type. I get this error when querying, `failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [productTimings] is not of nested type`. Is there any extra steps that I need to do to make sure the mapping is of type nested?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there but the query was heavily malformed.

Try this — I've adapted it to match the sample document from above:

```js
const body = {
  size,
  from: pageno * size,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": { shopId }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "productTimings",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "productTimings.startHour": {
                        "gte": 8
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "productTimings.endHour": {
                        "lte": 9
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "productTimings.dayOfWeek": "Fri"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

prodDetails = await client.search({ 
    index: 'productss',
    body: body
})
```

Tip: I'd recommend using a [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query instead of `match`. Even before that, I'd convert the `shopId` and `dayOfWeek` to [`keywords`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword-field-type). When they're mapped as `String` (= [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param)), they'll be lowercased by the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) — and you don't want that. You likely want case-sensitive, exact matches that the `keyword` mapping guarantees.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. The issue I am facing is with the startMin & endMin. If starttime is 8:30 and Endtime is 9:45, then 9:15 will not fetch any result. 

Is there any way to concat startHour+endHour and then apply the grather than or less than range?

Comment: I tried adding this instead of the range queries but got some errors: 

{   "script": {
       "script": {
                "inline": "(String.valueOf(doc['startHour'].value) + string.valueOf(doc['startMin'].value)).intValue() < params.inp",
                                    "lang": "painless",
                                    "params": {
                                      "inp": 915
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              },

Comment: If you're gonna use concatenated strings, use this in a nested query: `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(doc['productTimings.startHour'].value) + String.valueOf(doc['productTimings.startMin'].value)) < params.inp`